# class that accepts duplicates and sorts input automatically

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I know that The ***Treeset*** Sort the input automatically but don't accept duplicates.Is there any class Collection in java that allows Duplicate values  or objects and Sort the given Input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java list that automatically sorts elements as I add them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097974/java-list-that-automatically-sorts-elements-as-i-add-them)

Comment: You can have a custom Comparator which never return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User List Implementation and sort them using `Collection.sort()`

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("A");

    System.out.println(list);
    Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
```

But if you are using you object in collection then Implement `Comparable` interface and override `compare(Object obj,Object obj1)` method.

Otherwise you can write your `Comparator` then pass it to `sort` method.

Answer (score 1):

[List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), along with `Collection.sort()` would fit your needs.