# I have a list of integers , how to sort it?

Tags: java

Have a list of integers like

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I think calling `l.contains` is slow, how to sort the list. After sorting, will `l.contains` behave faster?

Is there any sortedList I can use directly?

Comment: `l.sort()` doesn't work? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29

Comment: @Oliver `sort` is not defined on `Collection`

Comment: You might find this useful also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661065/a-good-sorted-list-for-java

Comment: I believe sorting the list will only make `.contains()` faster for lower numbers, and slower for higher numbers. It will remain O(n). Converting to a `Set`, on the other hand, will allow for faster lookups.

Answer (score 13):

It can't get simpler than this.

```
Collections.sort(l);
```

Answer (score 7):

Sorting of list would not make contains operation faster. It still be O(n) in worst case.

However you can sort your list and perform the binary search on top of it.

```
Collections.sort(l);
Collections.binarySearch(l, a);
```

This will take O(lg(n)) time in worst case.

But if you want a high performance contains operation consider using `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`. It takes nearly constant time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Collections.sort(l);`

Answer (score 2):

The `sort()` method from [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) can help you sort your ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

contains() on a ArrayList doesn't assume the array is sorted, even if it is.  You'll want to use some sort of set (HashSet will give you the best find performance, and a LinkedHashSet will retain the order.  Even a TreeList will give you better performance.)

Answer (score 0):

**TreeSet** may be useful for you.

```
SortedSet<Integer> s = new TreeSet<Integer>(l);
```

Comment: Note that this will also remove duplicates, which may not be what user705414 wanted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the main aim of the problem is to make **l.contains** to be executed faster.

Answer (score 0):

If `Collections.sort(l)` does not give the desired result, try `Collections.sort(l, comparator)` where "comparator" is something like this:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
  public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs)
  {
    // perform the desired comparison.
  }
}
```

Edit: I'll leave this up, but the answer by "Mairbek Khadikov" seems to be the best answer.