# Best list implementation for ordering objects by field in Java?

Tags: java

The situation I have is that I currently have a LinkedList of 'Appointment' objects which have the following attributes:

'patient'
'date'
'type'

The only functionality required is to loop through this LinkedList and display each appointment in order of 'date'. So, each time a new Appointment is created (using a method called 'addAppointment' in the same class as the LinkedList of appointments), the method will sort the linked list using a Comparator.

However, I was wondering if this is bad practice and if there is a better way to do this? I never need to get the 'Appointment' object by its index and so would it be better practice to use a Priority Queue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good Sorted List for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661065/a-good-sorted-list-for-java)

Comment: I also forgot to add that the attributes may need to be modified, like if an appointment changes date or type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In this case, the elements are all going to be distinguishable, and I think `SortedSet` makes the most sense.

Comment: @chrylis I don't disagree, but that's an interface. I assume you mean [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No not really a duplicate. This Question is about maintaining a sorted order by field on the objects. That [other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661065/642706) is about random access to an element in the set.

Comment: @BasilBourque Fair. Did you notice this is from 10 years ago? I feel so old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would disagree with everyone here so far and say go ahead and use a simple ArrayList. Your main use case is just to loop through the list and display it in order, right? You can sort an array list by using the Collections.sort() method, which will sort any list of objects implementing Comparable. So just implement Comparable in your Appointment object (only need to provide a .compareTo() method...the API explains this well, or the Java Trail on Collections) and your sorting will then be painless and easy. My experience is this is better performing than an object like TreeSet or a LinkedList.

Now those would be better performing if you were always inserting into the middle of the list a lot, but you seem to mostly be reading this list from what you said, so go for the ArrayList.

Comment: This very good method indeed for sets of objects that you need to sort for example only a few times per program run. The problem with `TreeMap` or similar containers is that they pretty much sort the list every time you add a new entry there.

Comment: I do need to sort the list every time I add a new entry because the application requires new Appointment objects to be created in run-time and then added to the list.

Comment: ArrayList may not be best then. TreeSet may be better. It may also be meaningless. Adding to a TreeSet does maintain sorted order, but I would consider how often the list is simply read versus how often items get added. If there are enough additions, you may see better performance with TreeSet, once you get enough items (we're talking a lot). Sorting with Collections.sort() is O(n log n). Adding to a TreeSet is O(log n). By the way if you do use TreeSet, watch out how you implement hashcode and equals. If you only compare items on date, two items with same date will overwrite each other.

Answer (score 1):

### `NavigableSet`

The [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html), and its predecessor, `SortedSet`, define a contract for a distinct (no duplicates allowed) collection of objects maintained in a certain order.

The [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html) class bundled with Java implements this interface. For concurrency, or for very large collections, use [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html).

You said:

> 'Appointment' objects which have the following attributes: 'patient' 'date' 'type'

```
record Appointment ( String patient , LocalDate date , String type ) {}
```

Define a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to control the sorting. We pass a method reference to access the member field by which we want to sort. In our example that is the `LocalDate` field named `date`.

```java
Comparator < Appointment > comparator = Comparator.comparing( Appointment :: date );
```

Track our appointments. Specify the comparator to use automatically as elements added to this set.

```java
NavigableSet < Appointment > appointments = new TreeSet <>( comparator );
```

Sample data.

```java
appointments.addAll(
        List.of(
                new Appointment( "Alice" , LocalDate.of( 2025 , Month.APRIL , 23 ) , "trim" ) ,
                new Appointment( "Bob" , LocalDate.of( 2025 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) , "dye" ) ,
                new Appointment( "Carol" , LocalDate.of( 2025 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) , "set" )
        )
);
```

Add another element.

```java
appointments.add(
        new Appointment( "Davis" , LocalDate.of( 2025 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) , "cut" )
);
```

See results.

```java
System.out.println( "appointments = " + appointments );
```

> appointments = [Appointment[patient=Bob, date=2025-01-23, type=dye], Appointment[patient=Davis, date=2025-02-23, type=cut], Appointment[patient=Carol, date=2025-03-23, type=set], Appointment[patient=Alice, date=2025-04-23, type=trim]]

Sure enough, the `Appointment` objects are kept in sorted order, arranged by the date.

You might want a secondary sort, to order any multiple appointments for the same date.

```java
Comparator < Appointment > comparator =
        Comparator
                .comparing( Appointment :: date )
                .thenComparing( Appointment :: patient );
```

### Sequenced collections

In Java 21+, we have [sequenced collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431), adding more interfaces to the [*Java Collections Framework*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). These interfaces include:

- [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html)
- [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html)

[`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html), `SortedSet`, `TreeSet`, and `ConcurrentSkipListSet` all extend/implement those two new interfaces.

```
SequencedCollection < Appointment > appointments = new TreeSet <>( comparator );
```

[image: class hierarchy diagram by Stuart Marks of Oracle Corp.]

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, use an `ArrayList` when you need random access and a `LinkedList` when there will be lots of inserts and removes. If you need a data structure that stays sorted, `PriorityQueue` is an option, but it's really intended for the scenario where you're just pulling the top element off sequentially. If you're needing to repeatedly iterate over the elements, use a `SortedSet`.

If a field involved in the element's ordering changes after it's inserted into any sorted collection, you should remove and re-add the element (preferably removing before modification).

Comment: A `SortedSet` will be fine as long as "duplicates" are not allowed however

Answer (score -1):

Use a `PriorityQueue`

Write a `compareTo` method for your `Appoitnment` object that specifies the natural ordering according to date.

```
PriorityQueue<Appointment> schedule = new PriorityQueue<Appoitnment>();
Appointment a1 = new Appointment();
Appointment a2 = new Appointment();
schedule.add(a1);
schedule.add(a2);

// Iteratively removes the earliest appointment remaining in the schedule
while (schedule.peek != null) {
  System.out.println(schedule.poll().toString());
}
```