# Sort a list i java with two elements (type string and double) in Java

Tags: java, sorting

I am writing a pension program and I am stuck.

The program looks like this:

First I read in a file where every line has the name of the person, the age, and their first deposit. 
I use a method called `ReadFile` to do that. Inside that method I call upon a class called `class savings`which is in a separate file to calculate their pension. 
But I have the following problem: I would like to sort their names according to their pensions (highest to lowest) but I don't know how to do that.

Here is the method in the Readfile class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public void readFile(double rate) {
    while(scan1.hasNextLine()) {
        String input = scan1.nextLine();
        scan2 = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("/");
        String a = scan2.next();
        int b = scan2.nextInt();
        int c = scan2.nextInt();
        // calculate savings
        savings s = new savings();
        s.totalSavings(a, b, c, rate);
        // add savings to an array

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any list here...

Comment: I don't know how to make a list or array.

Comment: Here you can learn about lists https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: Once you've got that, the thing you'll need is a `Comparator`: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm  Good luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [A good Sorted List for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661065/a-good-sorted-list-for-java)

Comment: Man for learning the basics Stack Overflow is absolutely not the best place. Things like creating an array or a list are extremely well-documented and you'll get faster access to the information just googling than asking a question on SO. Being a programmer is firstly about looking fo information, investigating, being curious

Answer (score 1):

1st, create a class say `Person` :

```
class Person{
private String name;
private int age;
private BigDecimal firstDeposit;
private BigDecimal pension;

//Setters and getters method

}
```

Now Create the `List` which will hold the information of every `Person` :

```
List<Person> personList=new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Now sort your list based on `Pension` :

```
Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getPension().compareTo(p2.getPension());
    }
});
```

Given you the hint to go about your problem, but as suggested by other users, kindly go through the basics of java.